# Frequency vs spatial domain filtering

Tags: matlab, filtering

I applied a Gaussian low pass filter on an image using MATLAB for different standard deviations and recorded the time each method takes. I saw that implementing the filter in the frequency domain is much more efficient (faster). Does anyone has an explanation for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you use `imfilter`, this function performs a convolution of the original image with the kernel (the gaussian filter image).

For going into the frequency domain and back, fast fourier transform (FFT) algorithms are used, and only an image multiplication is performed in the frequency domain.

imfilter will therefore take about N.M operations, being N and M the number of pixels in the image and kernel respectively.

Each of FFT or its inverse have complexity N log_2 N, and the multiplication has complexity N, for a total complexity of approximately N log_2 N, which is much faster than the convolution.

Comment: thank you so much, I have another question: Only in frequency domain you make the mask the same size as the image, but not in the spatial domain, do you know what size the mask should be in the spacial domain?

Comment: The size of the mask depends on how close you want the actual filter to behave like the filter you want to design. If, for example, you want an ideal low-pass filter, then a good approximation will need a large mask. Smooth filters (such as Gaussian) need a smaller mask for a reasonable approximation. But this is the whole issue when designing a filter: a larger mask implies a better approximation but more operations.